# Making an enemy shoot every few seconds

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

so I am making a 2d canvas game in Javascript and I want the enemy mobs to shoot a bullet every let's say 3 seconds. I'm almost done with the code , i made everything i just don't know how to make the function repeat.

```
//this is the enemy object
 function Enemy(x, y){
 this.sprite = enemySprite;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.shooting = function(){
    while(enemyBullets <= bulletsPerTick){
        var enemybullet = new enemyBullet(this.x , this.y);
        enemyBullets.push(enemybullet);//i'm adding the bullet object to an array .
    }
    for(var i = 0; i<enemyBullets.length;i++){
        enemyBullets[i].show();
        enemyBullets[i].move();//if there is an element in the array , draw and update the bullet.
    }
}// i left only the important elements of the object needed to answer my question
    //this is the enemy bullet object
    function enemyBullet(x, y) {
    this.x1 = x;
    this.y1 = y;
   this.r = 5;
    this.show = function () 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x1, this.y1, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath()//drawing the bullet
}
this.move = function () {
    this.x1 = this.x1 - 5;//updating the bullet
}
```

In my main file , i have a function draw() which is in requestAnimationFrame(draw):

```
for (var j = 0; j < enemies.length; j++) {
            enemies[j].show();//here i spawn the enemy sprite
            enemies[j].shooting();//this is the function which adds the bullets to the array , draws them and updates them.
        }
```

Basically , when i press the start the program now , only one bullet flies and disappears and i want that process to continue over and over again every few seconds , let's say 3 seconds for example , i tried to add enemies[j].shooting() in an interval and timeout but they are in draw, which is in requestAnimationFrame and it doesn't seem to work , if anyone have any clue how to help me I want every advice possible. Also if you need more information about the problem , let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)? That would be a very JavaScript-ish way to make a repeating task.

If you want something based on a per-frame basis you'd probably want to have some manual counters increased based on a deltaTime of some sort and reset at some threshold, but I think `setInterval` would be sufficient for your case. Don't forget to keep the `intervalID` returned from `setInterval` so you can `clearInterval` when your enemy dies.

Would something like that help?

Comment: I tried with setInterval , but it doesn't seem to work , maybe Because it is in a request animation frame function , which updates it very fast

Comment: i figured it out by myself , i used SetInterval and it worked , thanks for your anwer.